# A way to hide certain events in gCal from the month view?

Tags: gcal

Is there a feature or add-on that will allow events in gCal to be hidden from the month view? I have so many events each day on my calendar that it makes the month view virtually useless since the "key events" are always getting hidden with (+3, etc) in month view. I want a "key events" calendar but gCal will not let me do this without creating new events in the key events calendar. I want one calendar with all of the events, but a way to show only "key dates" in a month view. Is there any type of add-on or feature that can allow me to do this?